# MSAccess VBA code won't open Excel sheet if Excel is already running

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

When I open excel in MS Access through the following VBA code:

```
        Set objApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")  
        Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objApp.Visible = True
        Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("\\bk00sql0002\D_Root\Pre-Manufacturing\Excel\CommitmentLetter.xls", True, False)
```

It will not open if the Excel Application is already running. I need to first close the already running Excel Application then I can run the above code and it will open Excel.

How do I get Excel to open even if it is already running? Thanks!

Comment: If this is to be used by several people, they may prefer that you check if there is an instance and just use that, rather than closing the work they have open in Excel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Remou is there a way to simplify the code that msdn provides? Seems a bit complicated.

Comment: @Remou: isn't the issue you raise about contention of multiple users on the file, and not for multiple instances of Excel? So far as I know, there's no way for a user (even on a Terminal Server) to poke into the memory of another user and do anything with its running applications.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton As I understand it, Bruno is creating an application that will run on a users machine, before the application runs, instances of Excel are are being closed, this will include the user's own instances in this case.

Comment: @Remou: But "used by several people" in that case is no different form "used by a single user".

Comment: @David-W-Fenton In that case I have no idea what you mean. If I have an instance of Excel running and I run an application that closes instances of Excel, it will close my running instance, which I may not want.

Comment: The point is that any instance of Excel is not being used by several people at once -- that's impossible. Any instance of Excel is entirely used by a single user. At this point I'm confused as to what we're talking about so I'll just let this one go...

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I am quite clear what I am talking about and I have absolutely no idea why you are dragging in several people. Please note that I have tested with a running instance of Excel. It is by no means uncommon to distribute an application to single users that manipulates Excel. That single user can be running Excel on their own account when they start the application. If the application closes their instance of Excel, they will not be happy. I do not understand why you do not see this.

Comment: @Remoue: I'm not even addressing anything you're talking about in your last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Do While Not objApp Is Nothing
  objApp.Quit
  Set objApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Loop

On Error GoTo 0

Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

You probably also need to handle the case when Excel won't quit.

---

UPDATE

To use the existing running instance (rather than kill it):

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

On Error GoTo 0

If objApp Is Nothing Then
  Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End if
```

Comment: Could you please show me the code for what @Remou is talking about?

Comment: I'd much prefer to see this code with a real error handler, instead of turning off error handling. That way you would be able to recover in case some error other than the EXPECTED one occurs. I'm less bothered by the second example, though, given that error handling is off for only one line, but it still means you don't know whether the problem you're ignoring is the expected one or something you haven't even considered.